# in oi.select angularjs How to clean selected item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <oi-select oi-options="service.ServiceName for service in services track by  service.ServiceID" id="ServiceID" ng-model="ManualQuickDeposit.service" placeholder="Select Service" name="service" required>
    </oi-select>
    </div>
```

**button**

```
 <button id="divApply"  class="btn btn-info" type="button" ng-click="Next(ManualQuickDeposit)" style="width: 80px;">
                        Update
                    </button>
```

This is oi select options. I want to know the way how to clean the oi.select option by clicked  Next button. How to write this in angular way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IFO4sxODp5cred4KCNf3?p=preview) with a working example

In your problem,  your `ng-model="ManualQuickDeposit.service"`
so your button `ng-click` will be `ng-click="Next()"` no need extra parameter and in your controller you can do as below

```
$scope.Next = function () {
   $scope.ManualQuickDeposit.service = [];
}
```